# Can you run database queries in a PHP cron job?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, cron

I've tried looking around for an answer, and nothing seems to answer this specific question properly.

Is it possible to setup a Cron Job for a PHP file that contains MySQL database queries? As I understand currently, it is possible to execute a PHP file using Cron, but I've read some conflicting posts as to whether or not the PHP file can contain MySQL queries. I need to know for a site function I am planning where, periodically, a whole bunch of data from a database is run through some PHP and reinserted into the database with modifications.

Cheers

Comment: Yes you can run database queries using cron

Comment: I've read some conflicting posts as to whether or not the PHP file can contain MySQL queries. ???? You can definitely use sql queries in PHP

Comment: If you take cron out of the equation, it's just a PHP script that is executed via the command line. If you can run a mysql query, so can cron (root).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run any PHP file using CRON. Just add the PHP file in CRON using syntax:

```
01 04 1 1 1 /var/www/somedirectory/somephpfile.php
```

You can see more options for CRON [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Then somephpfile.php can have any CRUD operation which is supported by PHP.

In short you can call any PHP file which is error free and it will definitely run (if it runs when you try to run it directly in browser)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

I was using mysql function inside cron job php file. 
you can Insert/Update/Delete and select and any db operation with php.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
But, a well structured application must has some models to interact with database and I hope the same case with you. Load models in cron job and call defined method in model. This will saves time and code redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can !

```
* * * * * /your/bin/php yourProgram.php
```

or usr a shell program like :

```
* * * * * /your/shell/program.sh
```

with for example in your program.sh

```
/your/bin/php yourProgram.php
/your/bin/php yourProgram2.php 
etc...
```